# How do I connect wires to this micro stepper motor?

Tags: pcb, motor, connector, stepper-motor, flexible

I want to use these motors for a small tactile display but I'm not sure how to connect to the motor connections they're so small.

I was thinking about potentially using a semi-rigid PCB. If so is this something that I can make myself or something I'd want to get manufactured. The goal is to have an array of maybe 20 of these, with each being independently controllable.

Any tips or advice would be really helpful. I'm a bit lost here.

[image: A micro 3V-5V 2-phase 4-wire]

Comment: For a one-off, 30 gauge silicone wire, solder, and tiny heat-shrink.  For an array, yes, flex PCB.  Some of the prototype vendors will do it, but it's not cheap.  I'd strongly recommend you prove out the idea with one or two hand wired ones, it's not very clear that this is really the right actuator for your purposes... you have mechanical "state" there but no clear sense how you'll discover it at initialization or to recover after mechanical overload has lead mechanical state to deviate from its software modeling.

Comment: You might also consider if someone else sells these with a cable (probably flat flex) on them, as they'd be in whatever they were used in.